# How serious is bear safety in the sub-polar Ural / Komi Republic / Yugyd Va?

Tags: safety, bears, russia

In Norway, Sweden, and Finland, there are resident bears, but they rarely go near people, nobody practices the kind of bear safety that is necessary in parts of North America, and this does not lead to problems.  The only problems I've heard about involved people with dogs, often while hunting.

How is the situation in the [Virgin Komi Forests World Heritage Site](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/719/), including the Yugyd Va (Clear Water) National Park?  Do I nead to hang my food and/or use bear boxes, or can I act like I'd do in northwestern Europe?

Comment: Even if you get superlative answers here, after your trip, please let us know what you did and how it worked out.

Comment: @ab2 This trip has been a dream of mine for some years, and it may be some years yet before I can go, not speaking any Russian!

Comment: Seems to be some information here: http://www.yugyd-va.ru/turizm-i-otdyh/prebyvanie-v-parke-oformlenie-prebyvaniya/rekomendatsii-po-predotvrashheniyu-napadeniya-burogo-medvedya/

Comment: Or rather here: https://yugyd-va.ru/Turizm-i-otdih/Oformlenie-razresheniya/-Rekomendacii-po-predotvrasheniyu-napadeniya-burogo-medvedya

Answer (score 1):

***Answer is work in progress!*** Still working on the translation.  Help is welcome — my Russian is very limited.

---

There are several relevant pages on the park website (all in Russian).

At the [*Инструкция по технике безопасности на маршруте*](https://yugyd-va.ru/Turizm-i-otdih/Oformlenie-razresheniya/-Instrukcii-po-tehnike-bezopasnosti) (*instructions for safe techniques on the route*) there is no mention of bears — the instructions are about camping, rafting, weather, etc.

The [*Правила пребывания на территории парка*](https://yugyd-va.ru/Turizm-i-otdih/Oformlenie-razresheniya/Pravila-prebivaniya-na-territorii-parka) (*rules for staying in the park*) do not mention bears either.

While browsing, I did come across the beautiful piece of [what to do when lost](https://yugyd-va.ru/Turizm-i-otdih/Oformlenie-razresheniya/ETO-DOLJEN-ZNAT-KAJDIY-ili-KAK-NE-STAT-ZALOJNIKOM-LESA): *Лучший способ успокоиться — это обнять дерево*: *The best method [to calm down] is to hug a tree* (similar advice seen [here](http://www.katterat.com/Courses.html)).

However, there is a dedicated page for [*Рекомендации по предотвращению нападения бурого медведя*](https://yugyd-va.ru/Turizm-i-otdih/Oformlenie-razresheniya/-Rekomendacii-po-predotvrasheniyu-napadeniya-burogo-medvedya) (*recommendations for the prevention of aggression by brown bears*).  From this page, the official advice is:

> Рекомендации по предотвращению нападения бурого медведя
>
> Памятка для посетителей парка

Advice for the prevention of aggression by brown bears.

Memo for visitors to the park.

> Общеизвестно, что бурый медведь – крупный хищник, сильный и опасный для человека. При встрече человека и медведя велика вероятность возникновения конфликтных ситуаций. На территории Национального парка такая встреча может произойти в любое время и в любом месте.

It is well known, that brown bears are large predators, strong and dangerous for people.

At a meeting between people and bears there is a large probability of the emergence of conflict situations.

On the territory of the national park a meeting can occur at any time and at any place.

> Большинство медведей  в обычных условиях стараются избежать встречи с человеком, и, обнаружив его первым, стараются уйти незаметно. Большинство медведей обращаются в бегство. Однако следует всегда помнить и четко знать, что поведение конкретного медведя, встретившегося вам в конкретной ситуации - непредсказуемо!  И только от поведения людей зависит, как будут развиваться в дальнейшем взаимоотношения этого замечательного хищника и человека.

Most bears in usual conditions try to avoid meetings with people, and, usually their first attempt is to leave imperceptibly.
Most bears turn to flight.
However follow always remember and clearly understand, that the particular behaviour of bears, meeting you in a particular situation, is unpredictable!  And it depends only on the behaviour of people, how the in future relations between this remarkable predator and people shall develop.

> Вот некоторые способы уменьшить вероятность встречи и нападения медведя:

Here certain methods to reduce the likelihood of meetings with and attacks    by bears:

> 1. Передвигаясь по маршруту, отдыхая в живописных таежных местах, всегда помните, что встреча с медведем может произойти в любое время, в любом месте, и вы должны быть морально к этому готовы.

Moving along the route, resting at scenic taiga places,
always remember, that a meeting with a bear can occur
at any time, at any place, and that you must be mentally ready for this.

> 2. Чтобы избежать критической дистанции сближения и не столкнуться неожиданно с медведем, необходимо передвигаться по открытым местам, где вы можете увидеть медведя достаточно далеко. Идите шумно, свободно и громко переговариваясь, и желательно группой не менее 3 человек.

In order to avoid critical distance convergence and not collide suddenly with bears, necessarily move in open places where you can see bears from sufficiently far away.
Come noisily, freely, and  loudly moving, and preferably in a group of no less than three people

> 3. Располагаясь на отдых, внимательно осмотритесь - нет ли признаков присутствия медведя. На глинистых обнажениях, болотинках, берегах ручейков можно увидеть следы медведя, а в пойменных местах места кормежки (копанки), где он копал болотные растения. Если у вас возникло подозрение, что здесь был медведь, немедленно покиньте это место и поищите другое.
> 4. Чтобы избежать появления "синантропных" медведей важно следить за тем, чтобы не создавались условия для их прикорма. Пищевые отходы должны сжигаться или вывозиться. Не храните продукты питания в доступных местах, изолируйте их, чтобы запахи не могли привлечь зверей.
> 5. При передвижениях максимально старайтесь избегать участков высокотравья, зарослей кедрового стланика, зарослей "лопухов" в поймах рек и ручьев, - мест возможного отдыха медведя на дневках. Дети должны быть всегда у вас на виду, не позволяйте им уходить далеко и лазить в зарослях.
> 6. Увидев случайно вышедшего на дорогу медведя, ни в коем случае не подкармливайте их, какими бы они не казались безобидными и милыми. В вашей подкормке медведь не нуждается, но начав прикармливать медведя вы воспитываете в нем попрошайку, который очень быстро начнет уже требовать корма, и если не получит его, то становится агрессивным и способен напасть на человека. Помните, что своими действиями вы ставите под угрозу жизнь других людей.
> 7. Избегайте ходить по тайге глухими сумерками и ночью. Помните, ночь - время медведя! Ночью нужно передвигаться с включенным электрическим фонарем.
> 8. Ни при каких обстоятельствах не приближайтесь в местах возможного нахождения медведя к останкам павших животных, другим возможным привадам. Потревоженный на добыче медведь в большинстве случаев переходит в нападение.
> 9. Увидев медведя в отдалении, не приближайтесь к нему, осторожно покиньте это место, обойдите его стороной.
> 10. При неожиданной встрече "накоротке", нельзя убегать от зверя (это бесполезно и только дополнительно может спровоцировать медведя на преследование). Необходимо, стараясь максимально сохранить спокойствие, оставаться на месте (как бы не было это страшно), громким криком призывая на помощь, или, медленно пятясь, отступать. Медведя в таком случае можно пытаться отпугивать звоном металлических предметов, громким криком, голосом и т.д.).
> 11. Категорически запрещается подходить к раненному либо попавшему в самолов медведю.
> 12. Ни при каких обстоятельствах не приближайтесь к медвежатам, какими бы они не казались вам милыми и симпатичными. Не пытайтесь их накормить или подманить. Немедленно остановитесь, быстро оглядитесь и как можно быстрее ищите путь к отступлению. Медвежата любопытны и если они направляются к вам, отгоните их громкими криками. Помните - где-то рядом медведица. Если она посчитает, что вы - угроза ее малышу, станет последним, что вы увидите в своей жизни.
> 13. Ни при каких обстоятельствах нельзя использовать для охраны от медведя собак без навыков, сноровки и силы для хотя бы краткого задержания медведя на месте. Помните: по Правилам посещения Национального парка, на территории парка собака должна находиться на поводке!
> 14. В целях защиты и обеспечения безопасности следует брать в сопровождение госинспектора,  у которого  есть служебное огнестрельное оружие.
> 15. В крайнем случае можно спастись от медведя на дереве, если успеете на него забраться.  Такие случаи спасения, а точнее отсиживания, на деревьях известны.
> 16. Даже если медведь все же пошел на вас, то все еще остается надежда, что он отвернет в сторону. Никогда не поворачивайтесь к атакующему медведю спиной! Побежавший человек почти наверняка обречен. При нападении медведя нельзя проявлять внешних признаков страха. Если поблизости нет надежного укрытия или убежища, необходимо встретить опасность, стоя лицом к лицу. Людей выдержавших таким образом атаку медведя больше, чем тех, кто смог спастись бегством.
> 17. При обнаружении медведя, проявляющего агрессию, нужно немедленно предупредить других людей, находящихся в том же месте или в непосредственной близости от него и сообщить в Национальный парк, ближайшее лесничество, милицию, районные подразделения МЧС, районную или поселковую администрацию.
> 18. И последнее - ВСЕГДА И ВЕЗДЕ встретив медведя, вне зависимости от его размеров, поведения и внешнего вида относитесь к нему как к грозному и мощному хищнику, с непредсказуемым поведением. 
>       К сожалению, даже полное соблюдение наших рекомендаций не могут полностью исключить вероятность нападения медведя, уже хотя бы потому, что невозможно предусмотреть обстоятельства каждого конкретного случая встречи с медведем. Поведение медведя непредсказуемо. Но будем искренне рады, если прочитав рекомендации, вы станете более осторожны в лесу".
>
> Памятка разработана заместителем директора по науке Шубнициной Е. И в соответствии с "Рекомендациями по предотвращению нападения бурого медведя" департамента лесов и особо охраняемых природных территорий Сахалинской области (2008 год), а так же книгой  М.А. Кречмара "Мохнатый бог".

Translation follows once I know more Russian.

Comment: Answers must be in English!

Comment: This is truly a copy and post answer.

Comment: @KenGraham I know, I'm still working on the answer, but I want to get the original before it disappears, as things on the internet may tend to do.

Comment: @gerrit  I am going to delete my answer.  I didn't realize you were In the process of translating yours.  I just thought it would be fun to see if the translator could handle a long essay.

Comment: I've no experience with bear safety, but I can help you with the translation (unless you want to work on it by yourself, as an exercise in Russian). I am not sure how specific these safety instructions are to the region (my thinking is that brown bears probably behave more or less the same there as they do in North America, don't they?). Translating the instructions into English is one way to find out.

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin I'd like to try it myself first, then I may ask you to correct when I'm done, thanks :)